# Jquery adding missing table elements when copying

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('#copy').on('click', function() {
  $('#input').val($('<div/>').append($('#sample').clone()).html());
});
```

```css
textarea{
width:400px;
height:100px;
font-size:14px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sample">
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td>sample content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>


<label for="input">Input</label>
<textarea type="text" id="input">
</textarea>

<button id="copy">Copy sample markup</button>
```

When copying HTML inside div, jquery is adding missing table elements to output like tbody and td if missed, want to copy the HTML in the original format.

Comment: You can't. When the browser parses HTML, it creates a valid DOM. The original HTML is not remembered.

Comment: Anyother way to copy content in its original format

Comment: What is your use case and why is adding `<tbody>` or proper closing tags a problem?

Comment: Want to paste MailChimp or any other newsletter code and then make editable for users and then they can upload the same to MailChimp as HTML

Comment: Well mail also uses valid html and `<tbody>` is valid. If you don't want it though you can store the html as text, or put it in a script tag instead of inserting as dom elements